# Calculate the difference between 2 rows in PowerBI using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, business-intelligence, measure

I'm trying to complete something which should be quite simple but for the life of me, I can't work it out.
I'm trying to calculate the difference between 2 rows that share the same 'Scan type'.

I have attached a photo showing sample data from production. We run a scan and depending on the results of the scan, it's assigned a color.
I want to find the difference in Scan IDs between each Red scan.
Using the attached [Photo of Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6LEp.png), I would expect a difference of 0 for id 3. A difference of 1 for id 4 and a difference of 10 for id 14.

I have (poorly) written something that works based on the maximum value from the scan id.

I have also tried following a few posts to see if I can get it to work..

```
     var _curid= MAX(table1[scanid])
     var _curclueid =  MAX(table1[scanid])
     var _calc =CALCULATE(SUM(TABLE1[scanid],FILTER(ALLSELECTED(table1[scanid]),table1[scanid]))
    
    return if(_curid-_calc=curid,0,_curid-_calc)
```

Edit;
Forgot to mention I have checked threads;
57699052
61464745
56703516
57710425

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following DAX and if it helps then accept it as the answer.

1. Create a calculated column that returns the ID where the colour is Red as follows:

   ```
    Column = IF('Table'[Colour] = "Red", 'Table'[ID])
   ```
2. Create another column as following:

   ```
    Column 2 = 
    VAR Colr = 'Table'[Colour]
    VAR SCAN = 'Table'[Scan ID]

    VAR Prev_ID = 
         CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[Column 2]), 
         FILTER('Table', 'Table'[Colour] = Colr && 'Table'[Scan ID] < SCAN))

    RETURN 
        'Table'[Column] - Prev_ID
   ```
3. Output:

[image: Output]

**EDIT:-**

If you want your first value(ID3) to be 0 then relace the `RETURN` line with the following line:

```
IF(ISBLANK(Prev_ID) && 'Table'[Colour] = "Red", 0, 'Table'[Column] - Prev_ID )
```

This will give you the following result:

[image: Another output]

Comment: Question answered, Thanks User8078111!